# Returning nearest document grouped by field in MongoDB using GeoNear

Tags: c#, mongodb, geospatial

I'm using the official C# driver to query a collection in MongoDB using GeoNear.

The documents look something like this:-

```
{
    "_id" : "1" ,
    "Resource" : {
        "_id" : "9",
        "Type" : "AAA"
    },
    "Site" : {
        "_id" : "4123" ,
        "Location" : {
            "Longitude" : 145.012345,
            "Latitude" : -30.012345
        }
    }
}
```

There are multiple combinations of resources and sites in a many-to-many scenario.

I have the geoNear working OK, but now need to filter the results on some other criteria.

I have the basics working, so I can for example return all of a particular resource type, however I need now for the query to return only the closest document for each resource type. For example if I have 10 resource types and several hundred sites (potentially thousands of combinations/documents), the query will return at most 10 documents... one for each of the resource types, showing the closest site for each (the query may in fact return less than that, if there are no sites for that resource type within the MaxDistance I have specified for the query)

EDIT

As I am using the C# library, I am able to somewhat work around this using LINQ to filter the results, however I'm still interested in seeing if there is a way to do this natively in MongoDB without relying on implementation.

I suspect I could MapReduce the results to achieve what I want, however I can't see how to do this in-line with the GeoNear command, and I'd rather avoid a two step process using an intermediary collection (caching these results is irrelevant in this instance as the query is always called from a different source location)

Answer (score 0):

When using geo queries you can tell MongoDB to return the n closest results, and you can tell MongoDB to check some additional field as well (like your "Type" field).

But as far as I know you can't tell it to return the closest match for each different value of that additional field. If you do find a way to issue such a query using the MongoDB shell I can help you translate it to C#.

I think you just need to repeat the query once for each "Type", and if you are only interested in the closest match set the limit of documents to return to 1.